# Docker logs interpreting JSON logs as string

Tags: json, logging, docker, docker-compose

Our Go server outputs logs to stdout in JSON, each line looking something like the following:

```
{"time": "2017-06-01 14:00:00", "message": "Something happened", "level": "DEBUG"}
```

Our docker-compose uses the standard json-file logger, which wraps each line in a `log` field as an escaped string, like so:

```
{
  "log": "{\"time\": \"2017-06-01 14:00:00\", \"message\": \"Something happened\", \"level\": \"DEBUG\"}\"",
  "timestamp": "<the time>",
  ...more fields...
}
```

But we don't want the log field to be escaped as a string, we want it embedded as JSON at the same level:

```
{
  "log": {
     "time": "2017-06-01 14:00:00", 
     "message": "Something happened", 
     "level": "DEBUG"
  },
  "timestamp": "<the time>",
  ...more fields...
}
```

Can this be achieved?

Comment: "Our docker-compose uses the standard json-file logger, which wraps each line in a log field as an escaped string, like so:" I don't understand how the logentry gets wrapped and where the additional timestamp comes from. Are you using some logshipper that adds those fields? Could you show an example logfile configuration that creates such entries?

Comment: @herm The default docker-compose logging option uses the json-file logger, and this adds a few fields: stream, time and attrs, in addition to the log field.

Comment: Your filebeat wraps the json log into the log field adds a timestamp and aditional fields. Thats notnthe docker deamon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this can't be done. But I can convert the JSON string to actual JSON in Filebeat, which we are using to pass logs to Kibana and Elastalert. To do that I used the `decode_json_fields` option under `processors` in `filebeat.yml`.